# Get a property of the prototype object after initialization

Tags: javascript

```
function Foo (name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Foo.prototype.bar = {
    n: function () {
        // How to get here after initializing the object foo?
    }
};

var a = new Foo('John');
console.log( a.bar.n() )
```

How to get here after initializing the object foo?

Comment: This pattern is generally not utilized because you need to jump through some hoops to make it work. Isn't really idiomatic JavaScript.

Comment: I know, but still ..

Comment: What do you mean by "how to get here?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you an idea of what's need to get that to work, here's a demo:

```js
function Foo (name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, "bar", {
    get: function() {
        var that = this;
        return {
            n: function () {
                return that.name
            }
        }
    }
});

var a = new Foo('John');
document.querySelector("pre").textContent = a.bar.n();
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

What happens is that the `bar` property becomes a getter that creates and returns a new object with a new function that closes over the `this` value.

This means a good bit of overhead every time you access that property. This sort of technique is necessary because the only relationship between object and property happens when the property is accessed. After that, the relationship is forgotten.

As such, nearly all the benefit of prototypal inheritance is lost. This should IMO be considered only for academic purposes.